# how to change the background color of TextView if EditText is empty in android?

Tags: android, background, android-edittext, textview, textchanged

I am using `Fragment` class in which I want to change the color of `TextView` When  `EditText` is empty after text is changed. I am able to change the color of `TextView` on text change but when the text is clear the `TextView` background  color doesnot  change to previous one. What are the possible ways to change the background color of `TextView` When `EditText` is empty after text is changed . My code looks like this :

```
public class Fragment_AboutUs extends android.app.Fragment {
TextView about_btn_call_customer;
TextView about_btn_Submit;
EditText about_feedback;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragment_about_us, container, false);
    //reference section
    about_btn_call_customer= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.about_btn_call_customer);
    about_btn_Submit=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.about_btn_Submit);
    about_feedback=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.about_feedback);


        TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {




            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                String textinEdit=  about_feedback.getText().toString().trim();
                if (textinEdit != null) {
                    about_btn_Submit.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_green));

                }else if (textinEdit ==""){
                    about_feedback.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grayColor));
                }

            }
        };

    about_feedback.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);






    return rootView;
}
```

}

Thank you in advance ...any kind of help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check `count` `onTextChanged` and choose the color:

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
   int color = count == 0 ? R.color.light_green : R.color.grayColor;
   about_btn_Submit.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(color));
 }
```

and you could do the same thing for the other `TextView`

Comment: I tried your solution ,it worked as a charm ,thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
   TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.length() == 0) {
                // for empty text color
                about_btn_Submit.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grayColor));
            } else { 
                // for non empty field color
                about_btn_Submit.setBackgroundColor("change your color");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    };
```